# Modeling EKF for localization of an Autonomous Mobile Robot

Tags: mobile-robot, ros, localization, kalman-filter, sensor-fusion

I've got an EKF for a simple two-wheeled mobile robot, whose states are the pose and the wheel's angular speeds.

I was wondering what were the advantages of having those last two states included compared to having the robot's speed and yaw rate.

I did so because I use the encoders to infer the speed, while the IMU to infer the yaw rate. I guess this is the right way to do it, but I quite miss a more formal explaination.

Kudos to all that can help!